# Inequality with two variables of calculus II lesson

Tags: inequality

In my calculus II lesson i have an especific exercise that asks, given a certain function with two variables,

F(x,y) = x^6 - 6 xy + y^6

If the extremes are relatives or absolutes.
First think i did to find possible extremes was the gradient function, and it gave that the only three possible extremes were (0,0), (1,1) and (-1,-1). Then the Hessian matrix told me that (0,0) is a sela point, but the other ones are minimus, with image -4. But i'm stuck trying to prove they are absolute. I coudn't find a example witch contradicted it, so i'm assuming it's true.
I'm thinking that solving the following inequality would be the simplest way to solve this:
x^6 -6xy + y^6 +4 \geq 0

But i coudn't solve it though. Once my professor did a "similar" exercise, where he somehow used weierstrass or bolzano theorem, but i coudn't understand anything he said...
Me and my friends are stuck in this exercise...
Thank you!

Comment: Here's [a reference for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you might find useful, which is preferred for writing up and rendering your math text on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking it! Just check the function as x and y approach positive and negative infinity (multiple combinations). The rest of the possibilities were found by the first derivate. The only thing that remains are the extreme conditions which could not be checked by the derivate test.

First possibility is that both variables go to infinity, this will make the value of the function infinite also.

Second possibility is both go to negative infinity. this will also result in infinity.

Now if $x$ goes to infinity, then no matter what $y$ will be, it the value of function will be infinity, similar case for $y$